# Generating fractional taylor series

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, convergence-divergence, operator-theory, fractional-calculus

I was considering the notion of taylor series which posit that the sum

$$ \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{i!} a_ix^i $$

Where:

$$ a_i = \frac{d^if}{dx^i}_{x= a} $$

Converge to the function f in a disc of radius $0 \le R \le \infty$

What is was considering was the fractional derivative such as

$$ \frac{d^{\frac{1}{2}}f}{dx^{\frac{1}{2}}} $$

Which is well defined using

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_formula_for_repeated_integration

For polynomials.

I wanted to use the half derivative to build taylor-series like representations for functions involving in this case terms of the form $x^{\frac{i}{2}} $ as opposed to just whole valued powers but it is not immediately clear how to do this. If I naively write:

$$ \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\Gamma \left( \frac{i}{2}+1\right)}a_ix^\frac{i}{2} $$

Where:

$$ a_i = \frac{d^\frac{i}{2}f}{dx^\frac{i}{2}}_{x= a} $$

Then it must be the case that

$$ \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\Gamma \left( i + \frac{1}{2}\right) }a_{2i}x^{i+\frac{1}{2}} = 0 $$

Over the same disc with radius of convergence R, that the clean Taylor series converged over, or else Taylor's theorem wouldn't be correct.

This statement follows from the fact that

$$ \frac{d^{\frac{1}{2}}}{dx^\frac{1}{2}} \frac{d^{\frac{1}{2}}f}{dx^\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{df}{dx} $$

Thus the series just mentioned contains EVERY Taylor term in it already along with a bunch of extra fractional power terms. IF (and i'm not sure if this is true) the series above too converges to f, for some region G that overlaps with the region of radius R mentioned above. Then it must be the case that all the fractional power terms must converge to 0.

So that leaves me mystified since then I'm no longer sure how to generate proper series using the fractional derivative.

Comment: Why must that be the case? You make a pivotal claim with no proof. Also, assuming that's the Maclurian, Taylor series about 0, you have to divide each term by $n!$

Comment: Yes, i forgot to include the n!, but to which do you refer when you state "You make the pivotal claim with no proof"? It's not clear to me what you are addressing specifically

Comment: It was the one along the lines of, the sum must be 0 or else Taylor's theorem would be incorrect.

Comment: I tried to explain it a little better. The idea is that in the "fractional series" every single Taylor series term is present along with some extra fractional power stuff. From here it follows that if the fractional series must converge. And it already has all the taylor series terms in it. The the extra fractional power terms must sum to 0 over the region where the normal taylor series converges, otherwise, the normal taylor series isn't summing to the actual function over its region of convergence (a contradiction).

Comment: Firstly, your indexes are very messed up. For instance, the powers of x should be fractional right? Secondly, when you double everything in the second sum, you only get "half" of the terms present in the first.

Comment: Correct, I did mess up the indexes, will fix!  And when I double the indices only half the terms are selected. Either the integral terms, or fractional terms. Since the sum of all the integral terms is the original taylor series from before, the set of fractional terms is what mystifies me.

Comment: I realized that there is a fatal flaw here. The fraction terms also consist of infinitely many terms of negative integer power. Those terms themselves definitely cannot equal 0 around the point 0 (for obvious reasons) so the idea of a fractional power series is probably going to be a lot more complicated than I originally anticipated. Possibly with an "annulus" of convergence as opposed to radius, due to the negative powers

Comment: I wouldn't give up, I'm sure there are some papers discussing this idea in more depth than I can provide :)